# Problems embedding a leaflet map in a xaringan slide

Tags: html, r, r-leaflet, xaringan

I am trying to include a leaflet map in a [xaringan](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan) presentation. There are several examples of this online, including in [this](https://nbisweden.github.io/raukrtemplate/presentation_demo.html#33) presentation.

When my colleague tests the minimal example below they get an interactive map on slide 2, as expected. But when I run this I don't see the map but just see a slider box with html code.

This works on my colleague's machine:

````
---
title: "Testing leaflet"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

```{r out.width='100%', fig.height=6}
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(lat = 30.2621, lng = -97.7382, zoom = 17)
```
````

Here is a screenshot of what I see on my xaringan slide:

[image: Here is a screenshot of what I see on my xaringan slide]

And this is the actual html code that appears in the box on the slide:

```
<div id="htmlwidget-627abe20cf1eb0297594" style="width:100%;height:432px;" class="leaflet html-widget"></div>
<script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-627abe20cf1eb0297594">{"x":{"options":{"crs":{"crsClass":"L.CRS.EPSG3857","code":null,"proj4def":null,"projectedBounds":null,"options":{}}},"calls":[{"method":"addTiles","args":["//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",null,null,{"minZoom":0,"maxZoom":18,"tileSize":256,"subdomains":"abc","errorTileUrl":"","tms":false,"noWrap":false,"zoomOffset":0,"zoomReverse":false,"opacity":1,"zIndex":1,"detectRetina":false,"attribution":"&copy; <a href=\"http://openstreetmap.org\">OpenStreetMap<\/a> contributors, <a href=\"http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA<\/a>"}]}],"setView":[[30.2621,-97.7382],17,[]]},"evals":[],"jsHooks":[]}</script>
```

Because this works on someone else's machine I assume the issue must be something to do with my set up. I've tried restarting RStudio and reinstalling xaringan, but after that I am out of ideas for what to check. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my session info, in case that might help diagnose the issue:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.3    rsconnect_0.8.16  htmltools_0.5.1.1 tools_4.0.3       xaringan_0.19     yaml_2.2.1       
 [7] rmarkdown_2.6     knitr_1.30        xfun_0.20         digest_0.6.27     rlang_0.4.10      evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: I see the same thing as you, and I can't spot the cause.  I suspect it's a bug introduced in some package update:  I'd compare package versions between your system and your colleagues to see what is different, and try installing old versions (using `remotes::install_version()` ) to see if you can locate which package causes the issue.  (It might be best to run `sessionInfo()` in the document itself, in case it is picking up different packages.)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @user2554330! 

You were right: my colleague had `rmarkdown_2.5` whereas I had `rmarkdown_2.6`. Installing v2.5 fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

This is an incompatibility between a recent change to `rmarkdown` and `xaringan`.  The current Github version of `xaringan`, available as

```
remotes::install_github("yihui/xaringan")
```

fixes it:  the discussion is here:  https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/293 .  It includes a workaround if you don't want to install the unreleased `xaringan`.